# Enable sitemap in sps2013 for intranet

Tags: sharepoint-server, portalsitemapprovider

How to enable sitemap feature in SPS 2013 intranet.

One of the blog, suggested for the permission on the site level has to be anonymous in order to enable site map.

Not sure if its required and what are the consequences of it.

Answer (score -2):

As per Microsoft Documentation:

> When you enable anonymous access to a Web site, you allow anonymous
>   users (and authenticated users who have not been granted access to the
>   site) to browse the entire Web site, including any list, library,
>   folder within a list or library, list item, or document that inherits
>   its permissions from the Web site. If anonymous access has been
>   enabled by the server administrator, members of the Site name Owners
>   SharePoint group can do the following:
>
> - Grant anonymous access on a site.
> - Grant anonymous access only on lists and libraries.
> - Block anonymous access on a site.

Reference:

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Enable-anonymous-access-3647cdd5-1ab8-48cf-b4ee-d1b652bbabdd?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE